# How to decouple npm package and replace the codebase with unpackaged direct version of the source code?

Tags: reactjs, npm, ethereum, npm-link

I am trying to understand the codebase of Pancakeswap frontend, the current structure https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-frontend has a dependency on

`@pancakeswap/sdk and @pancakeswap/uikit`

Which is available here https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-toolkit/tree/master/packages

So my question is can I just copy the folder and put in the frontend directory and replace all imports to use this path instead of the npm package?

If not what other options are available apart from deploying my own version of the UiKit.

Comment: Or you could just import it from the npm package and use a bundler to create a bundle for your web app. (webpack/rollup/parcel/etc.)

Comment: So import the original package, make changes and bundle it in the same codebase as a new package?